# Angularjs horizontal view swiping menu

Tags: angularjs, menu, swipe

I need to implement an horizontal swipe menu like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/9zuxH/447/

```
<div class="categories">                
        <ul>                    
            <li><span><a href="">ABCDEF</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="">DEF</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="">GHI</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="">JKL</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="">ABC</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="">DEF</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="">GHI</a></span></li>
        </ul>               
</div>
```

The problem is that it is animated poorly and it doesnt' use angularjs

i search a solution similar to Example 2
http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/touchcarousel/#carousel-gallery

but i need to implement it using angularjs

Have you any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you can try this angular plugin: http://blog.revolunet.com/angular-carousel/

Comment: that One plugin does not work with menu

Comment: Indeed, but you can get inspiration from it ;)